# Can I create three “veth” interfaces to build a virtual LAN in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute2

In Linux with `iproute2`, I knew how to create two [`veth`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html) (Virtual Ethernet) NICs and separated them into two network namespaces, then I got two virtual NICs and virtual 'cable' connected them.

Now I want to build a LAN in further, which should have three NICs, each has a single IP address and form a network segment.

Can I use `veth` (or whatever makes sense) to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`veth`s always come in pairs.

If you want to build a network segement with more than two virtual NICs you will need to combine `veth`s with bridging.

So lets say we have three network namespaces, lets call them “red,” “green” and “blue,” which we want to build a network segment between. We need to (names used are arbitary).

- Choose one of the network namespaces to hold the bridge, lets choose green.
- Create two `veth` pairs, `veth0`/`veth1` and `veth2`/`veth3`.
- Put the `veth`s into the network namespaces, `veth0` -> “red” `veth1` -> “green” `veth2` -> “green” veth3 -> “blue.”
- Create a bridge `br0` in “green” bridging `veth1` and `veth2`.
- Assign IP addresses/masks to `veth0` in “red,” `br0` in “green” and `veth2` in “blue.”

Comment: Thanks. I endded up with using of bridge to connect one end of all the pairs.

Comment: Could the bridge be in its own namespace, or outside of the namespaces entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make arbitrarily complicated LANs this way. I regularly do this with a few scripts (starting an xterm or two in every network namespace helps). Note you need routes in every network namespace.

There are also a dozen or so applications which simulate a LAN in this way and give you a GUI to create and manage them.

**Edit**

[Here](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/open-source-network-simulators/) is a list with more than a dozen applications; googling will probably turn up more.

Comment: Cool, I never though there are applications already.  Can you point me to one of them?